# Time Complexity of An Algorithm That Includes While Loop

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

How to analyze the running time of foo function with asymptotic notations?

I thought like that : 
`i=0` is constant time, `n%2==0` is constant time, `n=n/2` is constant time, `i++` is constant time.But I can't say that "`while` loop run n times".Becasue of `n=n/2` expression.

I don't know repeat number of this `while` loop.For example , if n is 5 ,`while` loop don't run, if b is 4 , `while` loop will run 2 times. if b is 14 , `while` loop will still run 2 times.

```
 foo(n):
    i=0
    while(n%2==0)
        n=n/2
        i++
    return i
```

Comment: For any n, n/2 will reach 0 in at most log2(n) steps, so the loop is O(log2(n))

Answer (score 1):

It is better to look [Best, worst and average case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case). In your problem, Best case have a constant time `O(1)`, worst case and average case both have `O(log(n))` time. Best case is obvious, it is when number if odd. Worst case is obvious too, it happens when your number is like `n=2^k`. You average is happens if your number is something like `n=p*2^k` where `p` is odd. But running time in this case is similar to worst case, because number of loop iterations goes down by dividing your range by `2`.

You can analyze this code similar to [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Even though you may find result in first compare, the average case has a `O(log(n))` running time.

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, also Could you explain that how to find log(n) and why best case is O(n)? I think it should be omega(n) .

Comment: best case is `O(1)` not `O(n)`. `O(1)` means constant time and happens when loop does not run. It means it happens if you pass odd number.

Comment: Oh, sorry , I misspelled . why not omega(1)?